# How to send server sent events on database update

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, server-sent-events

I want to send SSE event only when there is a DB update API called.
How do I achieve this? What is the standard market practise to achieve this?

my SSE endpoint looks like this

```
app.get('/send-events', (req, res) => {
    const headers = {
        Connection: "keep-alive",
        "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    };
    res.writeHead(200, headers);

    const data = `data: ${new Date()}\n\n`;

    res.write(data);
});
```

i want to trigger the above api when another api is being called. Eg below

```
app.post('/update-db', (req, res) => {
    res.send('db-updated');

    //perform db update
    //send the latest data thru sse endpoint
});
```

Comment: There are a few ways, and it could depend on which DB you are using. Does your send-events endpoint work, or is the client being forced to reconnect every few seconds. It would normally be coded as an infinite loop.

Comment: @DarrenCook this solves my issue https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-server-sent-events-build-realtime-app#step-2-testing-the-backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems by default SSE doesn't work with multiple clients/browser tabs.
In order to achieve that we have to send the event to all the clients that are currently connected/listening to the server

This code sample solves my problem

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-server-sent-events-build-realtime-app#step-2-testing-the-backend